# What happens if I compare a column with itself and it is NULL?

Tags: sql

What happens if I compare a column with itself and it is NULL ? Is this similar to floating point values where x == x only is false if the value is a NaN ?

Comment: It behaves the same as if you would compare this column with another column or a value. If any value is `NULL` the comparison returns UNKNOWN and this row is not returned. Even `where null = null` will not return any rows.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the comparison you do with itself.

If you do

```
WHERE Col = Col
```

any rows where `Col IS NULL` will have the `WHERE` clause evaluate to `UNKNOWN` (rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`) and the row will not be returned.

So `WHERE Col = Col` is equivalent to `WHERE Col IS NOT NULL`

If you do (not available in all RDBMS but standard SQL)

```
WHERE Col IS NOT DISTINCT FROM Col
```

Then this [will evaluate](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from) to `true`

Answer (score 0):

The comparsion with = is **not** NULL safe, which means the result is UNKNOWN

So you should check your database for NULL safe comparisons

On MySQL it is `<=>`

Postgres  uses `col1 IS DISTINCT FROM col2`

SQL Server hasn't one till Version 2022, you can uses the last option in query. Since Version 2022 it also supports `col1 IS DISTINCT FROM col2`

```
SELECT col1 = col2,col1 <=> col2, col1 = col2 OR (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL) FROM tab1
```

| col1 = col2 | col1 <=> col2 | col1 = col2 OR (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tTvHCZAq)

Comment: [SQL Server 2022 supports `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - on previous versions you can use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT col1 INTERSECT SELECT col2 )`

Comment: `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is ANSI/ISO SQL, optional features T152, DISTINCT predicate with negation and T151, DISTINCT predicate.

Comment: i like the mysql way better, but ok